# AVPlayer plays on simulator but doesn't on a real device

Tags: objective-c, avplayer

I'm implementing a basic audio player in order to play remote audio files. Files are in format mp3.
The code I wrote is working fine on the simulator but doesn't work on a real device. However the same url I use within my app works fine if I load it by using safari (on the same real device) so I'm not really getting the missing point.
Below is my code:

```
self.musicPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlTrack]];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

something extremely easy. The music player property is defined as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVPlayer *musicPlayer;
```

I also tried using an AVPlayerItem but the result is the same. Here is the code I have used

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlTrack]];
self.musicPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[self.musicPlayer play];
```

Finally I tried to use the code below

```
self.musicPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlTrack]];
NSLog(@"Player created:%d",self.musicPlayer.status);
[self.musicPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"Player created:%d",self.musicPlayer.status);

    if (object == self.musicPlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (self.musicPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [self.musicPlayer play];
        } else if (self.musicPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // something went wrong
        }
    }
}
```

When the method observeValueForKeyPath is invoked the player status is 1 and the play is exectuted but still not sound.
I tried several files like:

http://www.nimh.nih.gov/audio/neurogenesis.mp3

http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3

Any idea?
Tnx

Answer (score 17):

Check the spelling of your filename. The device is case-sensitive, the simulator is not...

Also, check if your ringer is off, you won't hear any sound when it's off. To prevent that, use

```
NSError *_error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &_error];
```

right before where you init the player

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion, adding these two lines before my player init and no issue. Right now I tried on my personal iPhone and a different network than the iPad and the network I'm facing this issue. At least I can say the code works fine. I will do the same test on the iPad where I'm working on. But I don't understand why, when I try this same code on this iPad i'm using for development it doesn't work but the same mp3 url works trying on safari (always on the iPad).

Comment: I think I found it - you're not allocating your player, so it gets released right away. Try `self.musicPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlTrack]];` - 
Also, add `[self.musicPlayer prepareToPlay]` right before `[self. musicPlayer play]`

Comment: The issue is solved with the line that you posted that I missed in my code. By adding this it's working fine. Tnx :)

Comment: My ringer was off!  Grrrrrr!  I want two hours of my life back.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried  all the things but did not work, the only think that work for me `AVAudioSession` to `playBack`
here is the code i used

```
private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp3") else {
        print("can not find path")
        return
    }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    } catch {
        print("some thing went wrong: \(error)")
    }
    audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer!.play()
```

please do not ignore the line in the above code
`try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)`