# Audio isn't playing in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, avaudioplayer

I want to play an "audio" after `5 seconds` when my app goes in background mode. The `NSTimer` triggered correctly. I am getting the `NSLog(@"repeat");` after 5 seconds. But, some how the audio isn't playing. I enable **Background Modes** in my target. I try with many other solution, found here in `stackoverflow`, but no luck. Can any one provide me the right solution.

In my `appdelegate.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSTimer* timer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *musicName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

In my `appdelegate.m` file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize
musicName,
audioPlayer;

-(void) playAlarmSound
{
    musicName = @"note3BreakOf.mp3";
    // Construct URL to sound file
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], musicName];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    // Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self playAlarmSound];
    return YES;
}

-(void)methodRunAfterBackground
{
    [audioPlayer play];
    [timer invalidate];
    NSLog(@"repeat");
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    //create new uiBackgroundTask
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    //and create new timer with async call:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //run function methodRunAfterBackground
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(methodRunAfterBackground) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733310/swift-playing-fine-mp3-file-on-simulator-but-no-volume-while-playing-on-device/27733443#27733443

Comment: @ David Karlsson, Thanks for your comment. But I'm afraid the question and answer is in SWIFT.

Comment: did you add "app plays audio" to your plist?

Comment: Yes, I did. When I enable `Background Modes` in my target, then it gives me option, where I tick the `Audio & AirPlay` in the list. And then the `App plays audio` automatically added in `Required background modes` in plist.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: OK, I got it. English isn't my native language. But I'll follow the structure, that's for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "playsAudio" to your plist and set

- AVAudioSession sharedInstance category to: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
- AVAudioSession sharedInstance
  setActive: YES
- UIApplication sharedApplication
  beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents

Seems some of that might be deprecated, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393495/playing-a-sound-with-avaudioplayer-swift)

In Objective-C:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Comment: I appreciate for your solution. But it is not working. I put it in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, beginning of the `methodRunAfterBackground` method. But it is not playing the music after goes back in Background mode. :(

Comment: I check with out `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and play the music in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Then the music playing well after starting the apps. So, the audio code is perfect. But some how the Background mode is not playing the music. I `NSLog` something in `applicationDidEnterBackground`. Though, It's print the log.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to play an "audio" after 5 seconds when my app goes in background mode

Well, you can't. If your app is not *actively* playing audio *at the time* it goes into the background, then when it goes into the background, it is suspended - regardless of your background settings. Your timer stops and the app sleeps.

(Many people solve this by playing a "silent" track as the app goes into the background, so that the app *is* playing something at that time, and can run in the background.)

Comment: You don't have to be actively _playing_ audio, you just need to have an active AVAudioSession (with category playback or playAndRecord).

Comment: @JohnScalo Not necessarily. Your session might be active at the time it goes into the background and you still might not be able to start playing in the background.

Comment: that hasn't been my experience and Apple explicitly states “Your app must have an active audio session before entering the background.” https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1668/_index.html

Comment: @JohnScalo Yes, having an active audio session is a necessary condition. But it isn't always a sufficient condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making the app active background. I am doing this in my app. I am using location manager api to make the app active in background. Then start playing a audio in background with the help of timer. You can use this link https://github.com/voyage11/Location to make the app active in background.Hope this will help.